# How can i use COBOL in my application?

Tags: cobol

Can i 'merge' COBOL with my application ?

 **I run Classic ASP with JS,Jquery,VBScript and IE 9+ with SQL Server 2000.**

With not so big database updates( about 500+ inserts in a day).
Its a company.

If yes, what the best or bests applications that can use COBOL and why's that ?

Can i create a application with just pure COBOL ?

Best Regards

Comment: What kind of application?

Comment: This question is incredibly general. What kind of application are you dealing with?

Comment: 1) what do you mean by " merge"?  2) As of today?  None that I can think of right away. 3) For decades the bulk of applications in the financial world were written in COBOL, some of these applications are still in use today.  Please give us some more context to work with.

Comment: @mbratch sorry i've updated the question

Comment: Maybe the most important thing to clarify: why do you want to merge your app with Cobol?  To recover a piece of existing code, possibly running on some mainframe and give it a web frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is incredibly general, however I will try to answer it as best as possible.

yes, you most likely can integrate COBOL with your application. It depends on what programming language you want to integrate it with. Just google "Integrate COBOL with (whatever programming language you're using".

Yes, you can create an application in pure COBOL. Many legacy applications use pure COBOL.

I recommend you take a look at this: http://www.netcobol.com/product/netcobol-for-net/

Which can let you compile COBOL on the .net framework.

However, a word of advice: I don't recommend integrating COBOL at all, COBOL is a notoriously bad language to use because it is incredibly verbose. Unless it is for legacy code, I recommend using a more modern language such as a scripting language.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted this view

Comment: I'd counter that last paragraph. It can be fun Domecraft. "Notoriously bad" source code, that due to its verbosity is still readable and maintainable 50 years later.   The new COBOL draft spec isn't even ratified yet, and it defines a very modern programming language, with that ever so awful readability built right in.  For examples of how easy it can be be to integrate COBOL with the web and linked into mixed language systems, see http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/gnucobol/#how-do-i-use-gnu-cobol-for-cgi and maybe http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/gnucobol/#does-gnu-cobol-interface-with-python

Comment: COBOL... verbose? Ever run into a 50+ character Java method name - now that's verbose.